# Window.opener undefined in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this. In other browsers, it works fine:

```
function main__pageeditor_new_body_SetUrl()
    {
        function getUrlParam(parentObject, paramName)
        {
          var reParam = new RegExp('(?:[\?&]|&amp;)' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i') ;            
          var match = parentObject.location.search.match(reParam) ;

           return (match && match.length > 1) ? match[1] : '' ;
        }

        var funcNum = getUrlParam(this, 'CKEditorFuncNum');

        this.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, arguments[0]);
}
```

But in IE you get this error:

`'this.opener.CKEDITOR' is null or not an object`

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: There must be some javascript missing from your example. Does something assign window.opener to this.opener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering - This helped quite a bit:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser

Answer (score 0):

window.opener doesn't always work in IE8 for security reasons. I think you can put the site(s) in the "trusted zone" so that it will allow window.opener to work.

If the two windows are in different domains then it won't work in any browser due to the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

please test once that what is NULL ??

```
this.opener
or
this.opener.CKEDITOR
```

Comment: It's mentioned in the question already: `'this.opener.CKEDITOR' is null or not an object`.

Comment: that means window.opener is working, but you are not able to access CKEDITOR object from the window.opener.
try 
this.CKEDITOR

Answer (score 0):

window.opener works when my security zone is 'Internet' in IE8.
Tried on
[Window Opener](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_opener)

Next, I wanted to try this on CKEDITOR itself so I went to [CKEDITOR DEMO](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

There I opened a popup '*window.open*' using Developer Toolbar and in the popup, I executed following code which worked fine.

```
>>String(this.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction);
```

Response

```
"function(f){var g=e[f];return g&&g.apply(window,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));}"
```

At this point when everything works for me, I would request you to upload your code.

Comment: I've uploaded the part of the code that is relevant to this error. I can't upload the full site as it's a private client. I've tried testing the security zone but that doesn't work.

Comment: I am assuming you are executing this script on a page which is opened through window.open. Is that right? Can you please add this line alert(CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction) on base page just before window.open, and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found this with a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=window.opener+ie8): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/0c014e78-8d35-4df3-93da-7f6a30b4ed8b/

The solution provided there is:

> Under the Security Tab in your internet options, click on the Trusted Websites Icon.  Now check the checkbox marked "Enable Protected Mode" and restart internet explorer.

Another [resource I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/iewebdevelopment/thread/6c2e23ca-9f85-440b-aec5-3a478528b268) suggests to also remove the site from the trusted zone:

> remove the site from Trusted sites list... it is probably already mapped to the same security zone as the opener (intranet). Select the File>Properties dialog in IE to determine which security zone a page/domain is mapped to.

Given that you've probably tried several suggestions so far, you might have changed enough settings to be in a weird configuration state. I'd suggest you reset all your zone settings to the default and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced Issue  window.opener getting null in my Web application running in http:/localhost:8080.If I placed the IP address/hostname instead of localhost then this issue doesn't occurred.

Lets check, I strongly believe this solution is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Your "this" context could be getting changed, depending on how you use the function.

change:

```
this.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, arguments[0]);
```

to:

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, arguments[0]);
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: While I agree that using `window` instead of `this` is a good idea, I don't agree that this would be a possible solution. The function is always used in the same way, and it works in all other browsers. Besides, `this.opener` is resolved to an object, just that it isn't resolved to the right one (for security reasons).

Comment: Also, the previous comment from the original poster was a pretty clear indication that it didn't solve the problem.